# Ropsten testnet vs ETH mainnet erc20 contract

Tags: contract-development, remix, erc-20, contract-design, ropsten

I was trying to c/p a contract and change tax wallet address for buy and sell transactions, but the function is not working properly on Ropsten as it works on mainnet. Tax is charged, but not send to wallet from contract.

Also, when providing liquidity, 7% of the tokens just vanished. That is a tax amount, 2% reflections and 5% to private wallet.

Is there any known issue regarding taxing for the buy and sell transactions on Ropsten?

Mainnet contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf527d24391c767b86b8e91385e1ce9c54d230a2b

Ropsten contract:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x25afd8f2a5347899d5a7a43eeb47e43c24279529

Comment: Hi Prizmwohoo! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What do you mean with "c/p"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.